# Azure DevOps Build Pipeline - Installing Applications

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a Azure Devops Build Pipeline running on a Ubuntu Hosted Agent which requires "**unzip**" to be installed.

When running the pipeline, I am getting this error which suggests unzip is not installed, which seems to go against the documentation.

```
unzip: command not found
```

Anyway, I have tried to install unzip using **apt-get**, but get an error about permissions.

```
apt-get install -y unzip
```

```
Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
```

I then tried again using **sudo apt-get**, but then I get an error about sudo not being installed.

```
sudo apt-get install -y unzip
```

```
sudo: command not found
```

So how do I install a package such as unzip (or sudo) as part of the Pipeline Build?

Here is an example:

```
jobs:
- job: Test
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-20.04'
  steps:
  - checkout: none 
  - download: current
  - task: CmdLine@2
    inputs:
      script: 'sudo apt-get update'
    displayName: Update APT
```

Here is the result:

```
Starting: Update APT
Generating script.
Script contents:
sudo apt-get update
/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /__w/_temp/a7297a55-95b9-46e2-985d-260e57d915ac.sh
/__w/_temp/a7297a55-95b9-46e2-985d-260e57d915ac.sh: line 1: sudo: command not found
##[error]Bash exited with code '127'.
Finishing: Update APT
```

Does anyone have a working example of using sudo in a build pipeline?

**UPDATE**
This has been a little bit of a red herring. This seems to only happen when using a container. When the container is removed from the pipeline, sudo and unzip exist. I have since replaced the container with a Docker CLI install and Bash scripts to do it manually.

Comment: Are you using the hosted agent or a private agent?

Comment: @DanielMann Azure Hosted Agent

Answer (score -1):

The script section allows executing the commands. You can include the command to install unzip in script task and that should install the dependencies. Below code should work for `apt` package manager.

```
- script: |
    sudo apt-get install -y unzip
  displayName: 'Install dependencies'
```

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/python?view=azure-devops

Comment: Doing this causes this error, as explained above. sudo: command not found